# Is it possible for Spring-XD to listen to more than one JMS broker at a time?

Tags: spring-xd

I've managed to get Spring Xd working for a scenario where I have data coming in from one JMS broker.
I potentially am facing a scenario where data ingestion could happen from different sources thereby needing me to connect to different brokers.
Based on my current understanding, I'm not quite sure how to do this as there exists a JMS config file which allows you to setup only one broker.

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, you would have to create a separate `jms-[provider]-infrastructure-context.xml` for each broker (in modules/common), say call the provider `activemq2`.

Then use `--provider=activemq2` in the module definition.

(I recently used this technique to test sonicmq and hornetq providers).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was worried someone was going to tell me there isn't a way to do this.

Comment: And just for the record, I think Spring XD is a simply amazing tool that takes a whole lot of headache out of streaming data for me.